# Haskell code with Gloss lib doesn't compile

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, gloss

I switched from C++ to Haskell and use Gloss to make games.
I wrote this valid code in a main.hs:

```
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game

events (EventKey (Char 'a') Down _ _) _ = RectangleWire 10 10
events _ x = x

main = play (InWindow "GameEvent" (700, 100) (10, 10))
    white
    100
    (Circle 10.0)
    id
    events
    (\_ world -> world)
```

Then the command `ghc main.hs` answered:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:3:43: Not in scope: data constructor `RectangleWire'
```

It seems some functions are missing from my Gloss lib even though I have the latest version installed. For example, this code, "Game Event" from the gloss-examples package, compiles and runs perfectly (so beautiful):

```
import Graphics.Gloss

-- | Display the last event received as text.
main
 = play (InWindow "GameEvent" (700, 100) (10, 10))
        white
        100
        ""
        (\str     -> Translate (-340) 0 $ Scale 0.1 0.1 $ Text str)
        (\event _ -> show event)
        (\_ world -> world)
```

Comment: Well, obviously it's not valid if it doesn't compile. AFAICS `Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game` doesn't export `RectangleWire`.

Comment: That's because `RectangleWire` doesn't exist. `Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game` imports `Graphics.Gloss.Data.Picture` and thus `rectangleWire`. I just misread the functions' name! Sometimes, it's better to copy/paste...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is failing to compile because a data constructor you refer to, `RectangleWire` is not in scope. The error indicates this:

```
main.hs:3:43: Not in scope: data constructor `RectangleWire'
```

Scanning the [documentation for Gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gloss/1.2.0.1/doc/html/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#3), it looks like you're looking for

```
rectangleWire :: Float -> Float -> PictureSource
```

A wireframe rectangle centered about the origin, with the given width and height. Exported from `Graphics.Gloss.Data.Picture`.